# Loop a python script

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working with a script that fits a line to a data set and outputs some fit parameters. The command that runs the fitter looks like:

`fitter = Fitter(hdf2.root.OM01, plot=False)`.

I'd like to loop this command so that it outputs the fit parameters for the files `'hdf2.01', 'hdf2.02', ... 'hdf2.50'`

How can I loop this code?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Python syntax... can you post an actual code snippet?

Comment: do you mean `fitter = Fitter('hdf2.01')`?

Comment: What would you like to see? The Fitter function is very lengthy as you would expect, but I have a short script that contains the code mentioned above. It opens the data file and runs the fitter:

`hdf2 = tables.openFile('waveforms.hdf5')`
`fitter = Fitter(hdf2.root.OM01, plot=False)`

I'd like to modify this script so that I can loop through the "01" part.

Comment: Yes Jason, that's what I meant.

Comment: Edit your question to include the new/updated information for `fitter`.

Comment: Have you tried to loop it yet or are you asking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: I edited the question to add single quotes, it'll show if it's reviewed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an object that has numbered properties (`OM01` through `OM50`). You can generate these attribute names with a loop, and use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to retrieve them from the object.

If your object is called `root`, as it is in your comment, you could do the following:

```
parameters = []
for i in range(1, 51):
    parameter = getattr(root, 'OM%02d' % i)
    parameters.append(parameter)

# now all of your parameters are in the parameter array
```

or, if you like list comprehensions (and who doesn't):

```
parameters = [getattr(root, 'OM%02d' % i) for i in range(1, 51)]
```

I guess you need to use these parameters with `Fitter`, which you could do as follows:

```
results = []
for i in range(1, 51):
    parameter = getattr(hdf2.root, 'OM%02d' % i)
    result = Fitter(parameter, plot=False)
    results.append(result)
```

**EDIT**: If your files just have the names "hdf2.root.OM01", "hdf2.root.OM02", etc. you can just do this:

```
results = []
for i in range(1, 51):
    filename = 'hdf2.root.OM%02d' % i
    result = Fitter(filename, plot=False)
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: If you were going to generate them separately, why not simply use a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY): ``[getattr(root, 'OM%02d' % i) for i in range(1, 51)]``? Of course, the real question is, why not just use a loop and do it, rather than generating a list of parameters?

Comment: yeah, I figured the loop would be easier to read, but was tempted to write the list comprehension.

Comment: In this case I'd argue the list comp is pretty clear. Not overly long, and not nested.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe that using getattr in this way will achieve what I'm trying to do. The parameters aren't attributes of the object - they're the result of running the fitter on a data file. What I'd like to do is something like this: for i in `range(1,3):
        fitter = WaveformFitter(hdf2.root.OM'54%03d' % i)`

Comment: @Brian, do you just mean something like this? `results=[]; for i in range(n): results.append(Fitter(hdf2.root.OM01, plot=False))`?

Comment: Yes, I'd like do do something like that. However I don't know how to loop through the file names, which is where my errors are coming from.

Comment: @Brian, I updated the answer, but I think I may still be misunderstanding something. Are the files called "hdf2.root.OM01", etc?

Comment: @Brian, cool, do you mind marking the answer as accepted? (click the checkmark next to the answer?)